# Compare two files on specific columns only line by line

Tags: text-processing, awk, syntax

What is the syntax inside for loop `if i in [2,4,7]` in awk. Also any idea how to achieve to do in below code. Thanks

Input :

```
$ cat f1
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7
col11,col12,col13,col14,col15,col16,col17
$ cat f2
col1,col2,col03,col4,col5,col06,col7
col11,col12,col13,col14,col015,col16,col17

$   awk -F,  '
   NR==FNR {
     a[FNR][0]=$0        #populate base file records
     for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
       a[FNR][i]=$i      #populate base file fields
         next
   }
   {
     for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
       {
       #if(i in [2,4,7])  <***How to chieve this column in list of values*** >
         #continue;
       if($i!=a[FNR][i])
         {
         printf "Line#%d, column:%d is different in two files.\n",FNR,i
         # ***<TODO print record from first file and second file after printing all mismatch columns>***
         }
       }
   }' f1 f2
```

Expected output:

```
Line#1, column:3 is different in two files.
Line#1, column:6 is different in two files.
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7
col1,col2,col03,col4,col5,col06,col7>
Line#2, column:5 is different in two files.
col11,col12,col13,col14,col15,col16,col17
col11,col12,col13,col14,col015,col16,col17>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you are doing line by line comparison on two files and on specific columns excluding some columns; that, all you can do with GNU `awk` for the word-boundaries support `\<` & `\>`:

```
awk -F, -v skip='2,4,7' 'BEGIN{ filetwo=ARGV[1]; ARGV[1]=""; };{
    getline lf2 <filetwo; split(lf2, arr, ",");
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        if ( (skip !~ "\\<"i"\\>") && $i!=arr[i] ) {
            print "Line#"FNR, "Column#" i " is different in two files."; mismatch=1; };
    };
}; mismatch { print $0; print lf2; mismatch=0; };' file2 file1
```

Or in any `awk` versions:

```
awk -F, -v skip_cols='2,4,7' '
    BEGIN{ filetwo=ARGV[1]; ARGV[1]=""; split(skip_cols, skip, ","); };{
    getline lf2 <filetwo; split(lf2, arr, ",");
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        if ( !(i in skip) && $i!=arr[i] ) {
            print "Line#"FNR, "Column#" i " is different in two files."; mismatch=1; };
    };
}; mismatch { print $0; print lf2; mismatch=0; };' file2 file1
```

explaining the code:

- The [`BEGIN { ... }` block](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Using-BEGIN_002fEND.html):
  this execute at very first and once before `awk` want to read any input.

  - [Using ARGV](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/ARGC-and-ARGV.html), `filetwo=ARGV[1];`:
    read second argument passed to the command (that is `file2`) and save that into `filetwo` variable; first argument `ARGV[0]` is *awk* itself and the third one `ARGV[2]` is `file1`.
  - after we read the parameter's value, with `ARGV[1]=""` we unset its value, so awk will not found that parameter (`file2`) for reading.
  - `skip="2 4 7";`:
    we defined a [variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Using-Variables.html#:%7E:text=Variables%20in%20awk%20can%20be,if%20converted%20to%20a%20number.) (see [Assignment Expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Assignment-Ops.html)) `skip` and set with the columns number we want to ignore the later.
- [`getline` command](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getline.html)- see [Using `getline` into a Variable from a File](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getline_002fVariable_002fFile.html):
  we are reading a line from the file2 and assign it to variable `lf2` (note the above that `filetwo` variable now contains the name of the second argument we read from `ARGV[1]`)
- [`split()` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html):
  we split the line we read from *file2* which is in `lf2` variable on comma character `,` and store in into array called `arr.`; now every fields of that line addressed by `arr[1]` (first field), `arr[2]` (second field), `arr[3]` (third), etc.
- Within [`for-loop` statement](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/For-Statement.html) we checks two things below:

  - The value of variable `i` that indicates column number is not seen `! ~` within `skip` variable value (`skip !~ "\\<"i"\\>"`; `\<` and `\>` are word boundaries anchors, GNU `awk` specific, so `i=2` will not match on `22`); next
  - checking that value of column from file1 is not equal with the same column of file2 with same indexes: `$i!=arr[i]`; if those were not same print the mismatched line number `FNR` and the diff column index `i` and also set a control variable `mismatch=1`.
- `mismatch { print ... }`:
  print both lines from file1 followed by line from file2 in `lf2` only if mismatch was detected and `mismatch` variable was set within `if` statement; and reset the variable `mismatch=0` for next line.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly  :

- you want to do a for loop on all fields : for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) { ... }
- and inside: you want to SKIP when i is one of 4 values (in awk, "continue" will bypass the rest of the current for loop and go to the next iteration

A simple way: if you want to be able to skip fields, you can do this by using the following technique

```
BEGIN { skip[2]++; skip[3]++; skip[22]++; skip[23]++ }

....
 for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
   if (i in skip) { continue ; rem="Will skip for values defined in skip array indexes" }
   ...
```

Instead of defining "skip" from a BEGIN section, you could also have a file with the 4 indexes to be skipped (1 on each line), and read that file using the NR==FNR condition, populating the skip array with this, and then when NR!=FNR (when reading the source file) you use the above method to skip those fields.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs, yes this is the first part I want to achieve. I will check this and try to implement in my code and will update in a while. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    FS=","
    split("2,4,7",tmp)
    for (i in tmp) {
        skipFldNrs[tmp[i]]
    }
}
NR==FNR {
    old[FNR] = $0
    next
}
FNR == 1 {
    for (fldNr=1; fldNr<=NF; fldNr++) {
        if ( !(fldNr in skipFldNrs) ) {
            chkFldNrs[++numToChk] = fldNr
        }
    }
}
old[FNR] != $0 {
    split(old[FNR],o)
    for (i=1; i<=numToChk; i++) {
        fldNr = chkFldNrs[i]
        if ( o[fldNr] != $fldNr ) {
            printf "Line#%d, column:%d is different in two files (\"%s\" vs \"%s\").\n", FNR, fldNr, o[fldNr], $fldNr
        }
    }
}
```

```
$ awk  -f tst.awk f1 f2
Line#1, column:3 is different in two files ("col3" vs "col03").
Line#1, column:6 is different in two files ("col6" vs "col06").
Line#2, column:5 is different in two files ("col15" vs "col015").
```